# How to pass data beetween author to publish and vice versa in AEM /CQ5

Tags: aem

I have very different requirement in AEM.

A author will initiate workflow. Workflow will activate the page on publish and It is still running on author instance. On publish a workflow will trigger (May be using Launcher) on the activated page and will call some third party service.Third party service returns result and pass to author instance. workflow which is already running on author instance, will read the result coming from publish , do the necessary things and notify the author. Author will login to his inbox and he may complete the workflow or redo.

I know it is a bit different . Please share your thoughts, how can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the usecase here ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Replication and Reverse Replication Agents to exchange data from Author <-> Publish (1).

But based on your description I'd suggest you do not replicate the data at all but you could simply call the third party service directly from the author instance - using an EventHandler or WorkflowLauncher.

(1): https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/configuring/replication.html#Configuring%20Reverse%20Replication

Comment: Thanks Mr. Oliver. Client wants to call Third party service from Publish only. I understand, calling third party service from author is the right solution but client is not agreeing upon it.

Comment: @Satish maybe the client ha security concerns. But if you make it clear the author server will be in control of the communication of the third party service, e.g. the author is doing a pull and it is not a push from the third party service, maybe you can convince him. Everything else would be very cumbersome, failure prone and thus hard to test.